# select within 20 kilometers based on latitude/longitude

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have a mysql table structured as per the example below:

```
POSTAL_CODE_ID|PostalCode|City|Province|ProvinceCode|CityType|Latitude|Longitude
7|A0N 2J0|Ramea|Newfoundland|NL|D|48.625599999999999|-58.9758
8|A0N 2K0|Francois|Newfoundland|NL|D|48.625599999999999|-58.9758
9|A0N 2L0|Grey River|Newfoundland|NL|D|48.625599999999999|-58.9758
```

now what i am trying to do is create a query that will select results within selected kilometers of a searched location

so lets say they search for "grey river" and select "find all results within 20 kilometers"

it should obviously select "grey river", but it should also select all locations within 20 kilometers of grey river based on the latitudes and longitudes.

i really have no idea how to do this. i've read up on the haversine formula but have no idea how to apply this to a mysql SELECT.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
JOIN    mytable mn
ON      ACOS(COS(RADIANS(m.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(mn.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(mn.longitude) - RADIANS(m.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(m.latitude)) * SIN(radians(mn.latitude))) <= 20 / 6371.0
WHERE   m.name = 'grey river'
```

If your table is `MyISAM` you may want to store your points in a native geometry format and create a `SPATIAL` index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD position POINT;

UPDATE  mytable
SET     position = POINT(latitude, longitude);

ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY position NOT NULL;

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sx_mytable_position ON mytable (position);

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
JOIN    mytable mn
ON      MBRContains
                (
                LineString
                        (
                        Point
                                (
                                X(m.position) - 0.009 * 20,
                                Y(m.position) - 0.009 * 20 / COS(RADIANS(X(m.position)))
                                ),
                        Point
                                (
                                X(m.position) + 0.009 * 20,
                                Y(m.position) + 0.009 * 20 / COS(RADIANS(X(m.position))
                                )
                        ),
                mn.position
                )
        AND ACOS(COS(RADIANS(m.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(mn.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(mn.longitude) - RADIANS(m.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(m.latitude)) * SIN(radians(mn.latitude))) <= 20 / 6371.0
WHERE   m.name = 'grey river'
```

Comment: Why did you deleted all your comments?

Comment: @Jitamaro: I moved them to chat because they're irrelevant to the question.

Comment: in your second code block, when you use MySQL spatial, why don't you use the DISTANCE function?

Comment: @Tomas: where is such a function defined?

Comment: [In MySQL spatial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html#function_distance)! Already present in version 4.1.

Comment: @Tomas: this one only works on planar surface. Also, are they implemented in any `GA` version? `Distance` is not present in `5.5.22`.

Comment: *"This one only works on planar surface"* - can you please cite the docs? They support the different spatial systems so Distance should be real distance. Don't know about 5.5.

Comment: @Tomas: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-class-geometry.html: *In `MySQL`, the `SRID` value is just an integer associated with the geometry value. All calculations are done assuming Euclidean (planar) geometry*. This function is not supported in `5.0` or above anyway.

Comment: Aha, so the MySQL spatial support is even worse than I thought. Not only MBR limitation but also this... ugggh... escape to Postgress. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `s`.suburb_id,`s`.suburb_name,`s`.lat,`s`.long, (((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((s.lat*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) * cos((s.lat*pi()/180)) * cos((($long - s.long)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) AS distance FROM (`mst_suburbs` as s) HAVING distance <= 20 ORDER BY `s`.suburb_id DESC
```

This query works for me to get all the lat,long between 12 km distance.I have `mst_suburbs` is may table which having the `lat` and `long` column.`$lat` and `$long` are my two php variable .and I am passing the desired  lat,long to get the nearest 12km lat long list from the `mst_suburb`. You just need to change the name of the column according to your table and pass the lat,long to query.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated algorithm, but [here's a link to one solution](http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/)

Comment: What about a spatial index or a space-filling-curve?

Answer (score 0):

You simply take your haversine formula and apply it like this:

```
SELECT   *,
         6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS( $lat1 )) * SIN(RADIANS(`Latitude`)) +
         COS(RADIANS( $lat1 )) * COS(RADIANS(`Latitude`)) * COS(RADIANS(`Longitude`) -
         RADIANS( $lon1 ))) AS `distance`
FROM     `table`
WHERE    `distance` <= 20
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Replace `$lat1` and `$lon1` with the latitude and longitude you want to compare against.

Comment: What about a spatial index or a space-filling-curve?

Comment: @Jitamaro What about it? Was that a part of the question I missed?

Comment: It would be nice if the down voters would leave a comment. This works fine if you have your lat and lon and want to formulate an SQL query that searches within the vicinity.