# RentFaster Scalable Map View connected to a database

Tags: maps, bing-maps

I want to implement a custom map scaling connected to a database. Similar to the map view on the Rentfaster website. Also, the RentFaster website uses Google Maps, however, I will be implementing this on Bing Maps
Where would be the best place to start off? And what would is the technical name of such a custom feature?[image]
[image: Zoom 1]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshots, it looks like the feature you're looking for is pushpin clustering, and can be seen in the interactive SDK here: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/clusteringmeanaverage
If you need hosting of your spatial data, check out the spatial data services module on the same page.

Comment: Thanks...I also found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945144/bing-maps-5000-pinpoints?rq=1) as a potential solution