# Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext in MBRContains LineFromText

Tags: mysql, gis, mysql-5.7, spatial-index

We have areas table with column named 'position' that stores lattitude and longitude of that area. The column 'position' here is of 'POINT' mysql type.

I read instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919661/select-within-20-kilometers-based-on-latitude-longitude) and followed the same but I am getting error on following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    areas
WHERE   MBRContains(LineFromText(CONCAT(
    '('
    , 72.836898 + 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(72.836898)))
    , ' '
    , 18.935255 + 10 / 111.1
    , ','
    , 72.836898 - 10 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(18.935255)))
    , ' '
    , 18.935255 - 10 / 111.1 
    , ')' ))
    ,position);
```

I am getting Error code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.

Answer (score 0):

For your MySQL version you need to use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    areas
WHERE   MBRContains
        (
        LineString
                (
                Point (
                        18.935255 + 10 / ( 111.320 / COS(RADIANS(72.836898))),
                        72.836898 + 10 / 111.133
                ),
                Point (
                        18.935255 - 10 / ( 111.320 / COS(RADIANS(72.836898))),
                        72.836898 - 10 / 111.133
                ) 
        ),
    ,position);
```